# Trading View Pine Script: How to NOT send sell signals on the candle if there is already a buy entry on this candle?

Tags: pine-script, algorithmic-trading

My first question here, and the picture is in the link behind: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ualLi.png) I'm trying to send buy signal when the close price is above the line and send sell signal when the low is below the line. But as you can see in the picture, sometimes a candle can have a close price above the line but low below the line, so it signals a buy and a sell order on the same candle, which ruins the results. I wonder if there is a way to code so sell orders can't be placed when there is a buy order on the candle? My code for this part is:

```
Buy_Candle=close>WMA_Final and close[1]<=WMA_Final[1]
Sell_Candle=low<WMA_Final and close[1]>=WMA_Final[1]
```

Please assist, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can't test without complete code, but this should work:

```
Buy_Candle=close>WMA_Final and close[1]<=WMA_Final[1]
Sell_Candle=not Buy_Candle and low<WMA_Final and close[1]>=WMA_Final[1]
```

Comment: Thank you PineCoders!